# custom enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

I'd like to have different enumerate/itemize environments which only would differ in color:

like so:

```
\begin{redenum}
\item 1
\item 2
\begin{blueenum}
\item 2.2
\end{blueenum}
\end{redenum}
```

What would be a smart way, to achieve that?

Comment: What should be coloured – the item label or the item body?

Comment: I'm not sure, a version for both would be nice :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions  withe the `enumitem` package, one for coloured item labels and on for coloured item labels and item bodies:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*. , leftmargin=*, format=\color{red}]
\item Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
\item Some other text. Some other text.
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*. , leftmargin=*, format=\color{blue}]
\item A sub item
\end{enumerate}
\item Still another text. 
\end{enumerate}
\vskip1cm
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*. , leftmargin=*, before=\color{red}]
\item Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
\item Some other text. Some other text.
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*. , leftmargin=*, before=\color{blue}]
\item A sub item
\end{enumerate}
\item Still another text. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*: you can use both keys `format` and `before` to have different colours for the item label and the item body.

*Edit*: Here is a code to define coloured list environments, with different colours at each level:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{colenumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[colenumerate,1]{label=\arabic*. , leftmargin=*, before=\color{orange}, font=bfseries, format=\color{red}}
\setlist[colenumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*. , leftmargin=*, before=\color{violet}, font=\bfseries, format=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{colenumerate}
\item Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
\item Some other text. Some other text.
     \begin{colenumerate}
     \item A sub item. 
     \end{colenumerate}
\item Still another text.
\end{colenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, i was more looking for a way to set the enumoptions as own environment - like redenum and blueenum stated in the question

Comment: But this can be done with enumitem . See  `§7 Cloning the basic lists` in the documentation.

Comment: @weltio: I added a possible solution. Please see if it befits you.

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for